# How to pass props from react class to formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to pass some props from React class to my functional component which is formik and then I want to add some callback function to get those data back on text changed. But not sure how can i make this done. Please check my below code:

Here is my Main.jsx class

```
// Some imports were removed to keep everything looks cleaner
import RegisterAccount from "RegisterAccount.jsx";

class Main extends React.Compoenent {

     constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
             username: "This is username value..."
          }
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container fluid>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterAccount} data={this.state.username} />
              </Switch>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Here is my RegisterAccount.jsx

```
// Some imports were removed to keep everything looks cleaner
import { Form as FormikForm, Field, withFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const App = ({ values, errors, touched }) => (
  <FormikForm className="register-form  " action="">
    <h3 className="register-title">Register</h3>
    <Form.Group className="register-form-group">
      <Field
        name="username"
        type="text"
        placeholder="USERNAME"
        className="form-control rounded register-form-control"
      />
      {touched.username && errors.username && <p>{errors.username}</p>}
    </Form.Group>
  </FormikForm>
);

const FormikApp = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues({ username, email, password, confirmPassword }) {
    return {
      username: username || ""
    };
  },
validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string()
      .min(6)
      .max(32)
      .required()
      .test("username", "error message of username", async value => {
        return true;
      })
})(App);


export default FormikApp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue you're seeing isn't from Formik, but from React Router. Your `Route` won't pass props in as `data` the way you have it:

```
<Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterAccount} data={this.state.username} />
```

Instead, you have to use `Route`'s `render` prop and pass props directly into the component. This should pass `username` into `mapPropsToValues`:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => <RegisterAccount username={this.state.username} />} />
```